# Shared Global Variable Between Different Files

Tags: c++

Before marking this as duplicate, I've already tried the "common header + extern variable" method.

From [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113854/defining-global-variables-between-two-cpp-files):

> In A.cpp (or) B.cpp write,
>
> `int gVariable = 10;`
>
> Remember to write the above definition in only one source file or else
> linker will complain of multiple symbols if you write in both the
> source files.
>
> And in the common header of A.cpp, B.cpp write,
>
> `extern int gVariable;`

when I want to include B.cpp into A.cpp(use B.cpp functions in A.cpp) in this example, it won't work. An example is [here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1ZJVarW_)

Thanks

Comment: `In A.cpp (or) B.cpp write,

int gVariable = 10;

Remember to write the above definition in only one source file` do you think you did that step properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same include guard in test.h and shared.h

```
#ifndef SHARED_H //
#define SHARED_H //

extern int testVar;
#endif /*SHARED_H*/
```

Also, you're not including `test.h` in `test.cpp`, nor actually defining `testVar`

```
#include "test.h"

int testVar = 0;

void toOne() {
    testVar = 1;
}
```

### https://onlinegdb.com/vCXz53DtJ

KamilCuk has rigthly pointed out that symbols starting with double underscores are reserverd, so I also changed your include guards

Comment: Do not define symbols with leading two underscores. They are reserved.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using the OP code and didn't want to change anything else than the things needed for compilation

Answer (score 2):

Three mistakes. You use the same include guard for both files

```
#ifndef __TEST_H
```

Make sure each header file has it's own include guard (typically named after the file).

Second mistake is that you failed to `#include "shared.h"` in test.cpp, so you get an error.

Third mistake (thanks Jack) is that despite what you claim in the question you fail to define `testVar` in either of your cpp files.